# unchecking a radiobutton and using case statement in dxCheckGroupBox

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have a dxCheckGroupBox1 with 3 cxRadioButton's inside.
Clicking the TdxCustomCheckGroupBoxCheckBox enables or disables 
the cxRadioButton's. Thats the normal behaviour.

However I would like the selected cxRadioButton to be unchecked
when disabling the CheckGroupBox.
Right now the last used button stays checked (though disabled)
after unchecking the GroupBoxCheckBox.

This does not seem to work.

```
procedure TForm1.dxCheckGroupBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  i: integer;
  CheckGroupBox1: TdxCheckGroupBox;
begin
  for i := 0 to CheckGroupBox1.ComponentCount - 1 do
  if Components[0] is TcxRadioButton then
    (Components[0] as TcxRadioButton).Checked := False;;
end;
```

Another question is how to use the CASE statement in this dxCheckGroupBox1
(depending on the selection of the cxRadioButton ?

Comment: Two ideas: 1. Set `EditValue` instead of `Checked`. 2. Maybe one of the radio buttons **must** stay checked?

Comment: Is this real code? `CheckGroupBox1` is a local variable and is not being initialized. I would expect an access violation. And another issue might be that you iterate over `CheckGroupBox1` components, but then, inside the loop, you access the `TForm1`'s `Components` array. And you do that with a fixed index (0). I believe what you intended is `CheckGroupBox1.Components[i]`.

Comment: @nil  yes, you are right. This throws AV.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt  The buttons have no edit value. One of the buttons does not need to stay checked if i disable the dxCheckGroupBox1.

Comment: Have you considered using a `TcxRadioGroup`? You can set the `Style.BorderStyle` to `ebsNone` to make it look like your `TcxRadioButton`'s, but it will let you control all of them at once in a logical group. You have `ItemIndex` useful for case statement, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there is no simpler way then this would do :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if cxRadioButton1.checked then
   begin
   showmessage('button1');
   end
else if cxRadioButton2.checked then
   begin
   showmessage('button2');
   end
else if cxRadioButton3.checked then
   begin
   showmessage('button3');
   end
else if cxRadioButton4.checked then
   begin
   showmessage('button4');
   end
else showmessage('None of the above !');
end;


procedure TForm1.dxCheckGroupBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
cxRadioButton1.Checked:=false;
cxRadioButton2.Checked:=false;
cxRadioButton3.Checked:=false;
cxRadioButton4.Checked:=false;
end;
```